# Pass a string as a parameter in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is pretty simple, I'm trying to insert a value that has a string as a parameter.
Let's give an example:
`const stringName = "User"`.
and my goal is to activate a function that gonna be called like that
`User.find();`
I tried the follows without success: `stringName.find()` but didn't worked and also `[stringName].find()`

Why I want to do that: I receive a `param` that is a string, and I want to search with this param in my DB so the real query gonna be something like that: `param.findAll({where....})`

I'm sure that there is a simple solution like the examples above. hope for help.

Comment: You'll likely need to edit the string prototype

Comment: How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Do you already have a function defined at `User.find`? If not, I don't understand what you want to accomplish. If yes, there's likely a better way to solve your problem than the way you attempt to (which would be pretty hacky)

Comment: @Ethanolle here's an example where someone added a `trim` method to all strings (before it was a standard). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231827/where-to-add-string-prototype

Comment: @A_A Edited the question to give you more explanations

Comment: I am still a little confused about the description. Are you expecting [`eval(param)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)?

Comment: No @Dummmy I try something else.

Comment: Are you using mongoose ?

Comment: No sequelize @Namysh

Comment: But that's not a big deal in the question whatever I'm using.

Comment: I assume param is a model name so the better solution can come up with is to import & store your models in an object you then do something like models[param].findAll()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store `User` in an object, and then access it with the string.

```js
const myObjects = {
  User: User,
  // Post: Post, ...
}
const stringName = "User"
myObjects[stringName].find('foo')
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably could do something like this:

```
let fncName(clsName) {
 if(window[clsName]) {
   let cls = new window[clsName]();
   cls.find();
 }
}
```

This however requires all classes that you are calling to have a function named find.  Probably better to do a switch on the passed in string and go from there.

```
let fncName(clsName) {
  
  switch(clsName) {
   
    case 'User': 
      User.find();
    default:
       ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't simply execute `.find()` on a string unless you define the find() method in string prototype.

If your goal is to execute some methods of an object, and that object's name you are getting as a string.

If that object is available in your current context:

```js
const param = "User";
this[param].find()
```

If object is not available in current context:

```js
let objectMap = {
  "user": USER
};
let param = "user";
objectMap[param].find();
```